# Why all my messages got statuscode 500 in custom route "meaage" of an api gateway websockets made with SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I got 4 routes $connect, $disconnect, $default and message, but message route always return a 500statuscode for all the messages received.

This is how I am sending the messages

```
{ "action" : "message", "data" :" hello" }
```

SAM Template

OnMessageFunction:

```
- Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
- Properties:
- FunctionName: onMessage
- CodeUri: functions/websocket/onmessage
- Handler: onmessage.handler
- Runtime: nodejs18.x
- Role: arn:aws:iam::543755020184:role/samTestRole
- Architectures:
- x86_64
- MemorySize: 128
- Timeout: 20
- Description: Function to handle incoming messages
- #API websocket
- SimpleChatWebSocket:
- Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
- Properties:
- Name: SimpleChatWebSocket
- ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
- RouteSelectionExpression: "$request.body.action"
- Message route
- MessageRoute:
- Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
- Properties:
- ApiId: !Ref SimpleChatWebSocket
- RouteKey: message
- AuthorizationType: NONE
- OperationName: ConnectRoute
- Target: !Join
-         - '/'
-         - - 'integrations'
- !Ref OnMessageIntegration
- # #Message Permission
- OnMessageFunctionResourcePermission:
- Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
- DependsOn:
- SimpleChatWebSocket
- Properties:
- Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
- Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
- FunctionName: !Ref OnMessageFunction
- SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${SimpleChatWebSocket}/*'
- # #Message integration
- OnMessageIntegration:
- Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
- Properties:
- ApiId: !Ref SimpleChatWebSocket
- Description: OnMessage Integration
- IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
- IntegrationUri: 
- Fn::Sub:
- arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${OnMessageFunction.Arn}/invocations
- Deployment:
- Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Deployment
- DependsOn:
- ConnectRoute
- DisconnectRoute
- MessageRoute
- Properties:
- ApiId: !Ref SimpleChatWebSocket
- # #Stages
- Stage:
- Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
- Properties:
- StageName: prod
- Description: Prod Stage
- DeploymentId: !Ref Deployment
- ApiId: !Ref SimpleChatWebSocket`
```

I am not including the template for other routes bc are they are working.

I tried to create another custom route but still the same issue
I created the same project but manually in the aws console and works perfectly

Any ideas what to do? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read - How do I ask a good question? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask